# Разбить текстовый файл на несколько

Tags: c#, файлы, строки, потоки-данных

Добрый день господа!!

Прошу вас помочь в разрешении следующей задачи:
Имеется текстовый файл(назовем база абонентов), в котором содержаться данные по абонентам, 
каждая строка может относиться к одному из N "регионов", в строке на это указывает определенные символы.
Строк много, примерно 1 500 000. Задача в том, что бы разбить этот файл на N файлов(по признаку региона).
Количество уникальных регионов заведомо неизветсно.

В настоящий момент реализовал вот так:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(label1.Text))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        str = line.Split(';');
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists("D:\\" + str[7] + ".d"))
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\" + str[7] + ".d", "Заголовок", Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866"));
        tmpstr = str[0] + ";" + str[3];
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\" + str[7] + ".d", tmpstr, Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866"));
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что AppendAllText работает чересчур долго. Пробовал использовать для записи каждой строки ... using StreamWriter ..., но прибавки по скорости не заметил.

Возможно ли реализовать данную задачу каким либо еще более оптимальным способом?

P.S.
Пробовал что то в таком духе:

```
StreamWriter[] swm;
swm = new StreamWriter[5];
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
    swm[i] = new StreamWriter("D:\\" + i.ToString() + ".d", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866"));
    swm[i].Write("TEST");
    }
```

Файлы создаются, но swm[i].Write не пишет содержимое в файлы...

Comment: StreamWriter не пишет в файлы небось потому, что вы забыли его закрыть? Программируйте аккуратнее. Он должен буферизировать, так что прирост в производительности должен быть.

Comment: `label1.Text`? У вас [логика в `OnClick`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_pushbutton)? Ню-ню.

Answer (score 2):

Хорошей оптимизацией здесь будет отказ от записи в новый файл каждой прочитанной строчки. Сохраняйте данные об абонентах в памяти! Например, можно завсети хэш-таблицу, где ключом будет идентификатор региона, а значением - коллекция абонентов, относящихся к этому региону.

А запись в итоговые файлы произвести один раз: после прочтения исходного файла нужно будет создать файл для каждогро ключа в хэш-таблице и записать в этот файл всех абонентов региона и сохранить его. таким образом, вы минимизируете обращения к жетскому диску, что должно отразиться на скорости работы программы.

---

**UPD.** Немного изменил идею - сохраняю в хэш-таблице в качестве значения не коллекцию абонентов а `StringBuilder`, который хранит содержимое будущего файла. Пример реализации:

```
        // Чтение и сохранение данных в памяти
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(inputFileName))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var str = line.Split(';');
                var region = str[7];

                if (!abonents.ContainsKey(region))
                {
                    abonents[region] = new StringBuilder("Заголовок").AppendLine();
                }

                abonents[region]
                    .AppendFormat("{0};{1}", str[0], str[3])
                    .AppendLine();
            }
        }

        // Запись данных в новые файлы
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866");
        foreach (var region in abonents.Keys)
        {
            var fileName = "D:\\" + region + ".d";
            File.AppendAllText(fileName, abonents[region].ToString(), encoding);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
public void ProcessFile(string filename, string targetDirectory)
{
    using (var pool = new FilePool(targetDirectory))
    {
        foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
        {
            var parts = line.Split(';');
            pool.SaveInto(parts[7], parts[0] + ";" + parts[3]);
        }
    }
}

class FilePool : IDisposable
{
    Dictionary<string, StreamWriter> writers =
        new Dictionary<string, StreamWriter>();

    string prefix;
    public FilePool(string prefix)
    {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public void SaveInto(string id, string line)
    {
        var writer = Get(id);
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }

    TextWriter Get(string id)
    {
        if (!writers.ContainsKey(id))
            InsertWriter(id);
        return writers[id];
    }

    void InsertWriter(string id)
    {
        var writer = new TextWriter(Path.Combine(prefix, id + ".d"));
        writer.WriteLine("Заголовок");
        writers.Add(id, writer);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var writer in writers.Values)
            writer.Dispose();
        writers.Clear();
    }
}
```